# Grain size and fatigue performance correlation for AMS 5662 Inconel 718

Tags: metallurgy, material-science, metals, alloys, fatigue

I am trying to do a literature review on the correlation between average grain size and fatigue performance of AMS 5662 (solution annealed condition) Inconel 718. The Special Materials Corporation datasheet (SMC-045, 2007, page 16, [PDF](https://www.specialmetals.com/documents/technical-bulletins/inconel/inconel-alloy-718.pdf)), shows a significant correlation between average grain size and endurance limit of AMS 5596. Basically the finer the grain size the higher the endurance limit, according to this reference. Some of our internal documents also refer to the "aerospace structural handbook 1995" which is nowhere to be found!

However, I am not able to find any scientific literature supporting this claim. It appears as if the correlation between average grain size and fatigue performance is non-obvious. Considering that fatigue is a chaotic phenomenon, finer grain sizes only delay the crack initiation thanks to their elevated hardness, I believe. However, as soon as a microcrack is initiated it propagates much faster in the bulk, leading to a total failure, I hypothesize. For example, the paper by [Almaraz et al.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2452321622003110) reports that double-aged material lives ~30 times longer at higher loads, but the endurance limit is actually slightly worsened! My explanation is that the tougher and more ductile the material the higher its tolerance to absorb hysteresis energy.

So now my question is whether there is any conclusive correlation between average grain size and alternating fatigue endurance limit for this specific material, AMS 5662, or any other advanced alloy of a similar nature?

**P.S.** I also posted the question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/metallurgy/comments/10j8j38/grain_size_and_fatigue_performance_correlation/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: Google found this, was that the one? https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19700011555/downloads/19700011555.pdf

Comment: @SolarMike yeah, I have seen a couple of results on Google, but I see no mention of grain size - fatigue performance correlation on those PDFs, wondering if they are the right reference my colleagues had seen in the past.

Comment: What s the temperature ? We used Inconels at higher temperatures and did not consider grain size.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I am aware that the Inconel family of alloys are very popular in aerospace and military applications, given their high-temperature performance. But we use them in vacuum and are more interested in their paramagnetic characteristics. They are austenitic steels.

Comment: The age hardening ( 700) are popular in aerospace . The regular ( 600) are more common in petrochemical.